How to configure firehose client to put record in a stream
I am trying to use firehose data stream and specifically putRecord api of the firehose service. I have created a class which takes firehose client and delivery stream name in constructor and a method which uses the api
class RecordPublisherImpl @Inject constructor(
    private val deliveryStreamName: String,
    private val firehoseClient: FirehoseClient,
) : EventRecordPublisher {
   // some other functions
   fun publishRecord(*params*){
       //pre-processing - params get converted to recordString

       publishRecordToDataFirehose(recordString)
   }

   private fun publishRecordToDataFirehose(
        recordString: String
    ): Boolean {
        val eventRecordBytes = eventRecordString.toByteArray()
        val eventRecordSdkBytes = SdkBytes.fromByteArray(eventRecordBytes)
        val eventRecordAsDataFirehoseRecord = Record.builder().data(eventRecordSdkBytes).build()
        val eventRecordAsPutRecordRequest = PutRecordRequest.builder().deliveryStreamName(deliveryStreamName)
            .record(eventRecordAsDataFirehoseRecord).build()
        try {
            val putRecordResponse = firehoseClient.putRecord(eventRecordAsPutRecordRequest)
            log.info("Putting records into $deliveryStreamName successful with response - $putRecordResponse")
        } catch (e: RuntimeException) {
            throw IllegalStateException("Exception occurred while putting record for stream $deliveryStreamName", e)
        }
        return true
    }
}


and i am calling this Impl class and the function from another component's lambda's execute function and using dagger to inject the firehose client
Module -
@Module
class AccessorModule {

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    fun provideAwsCredentialsProvider(): AwsCredentialsProvider {
        return DefaultCredentialsProvider.create()
    }

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    fun provideFirehoseClient(
        awsCredentialsProvider: AwsCredentialsProvider
    ): FirehoseClient{
        return FirehoseClient
            .builder()
            .region(Region.of("region"))
            .credentialsProvider(awsCredentialsProvider)
            .build()
    }

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    @Named("DeliveryStreamName")
    fun providesDeliveryStreamName(): String = "streamName"

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    fun provideEventRecordPublisherImpl(@Named("DeliveryStreamName") deliveryStreamName: String, firehoseClient: FirehoseClient): EventRecordPublisherImpl{
        return EventRecordPublisherImpl(deliveryStreamName, firehoseClient)
    }
}

Component lambda -
class GenerateActivity
@Inject constructor(
    private val recordPublisher: RecordPublisherImpl
) {
    override fun execute(input: GenerateInput) {
        log.debug("Received input: {}", input)

        log.debug("Calling recordPublisher...")
        val putRecordResponse = recordPublisher.publishRecord(
            "123",
            "String1",
            "SomeString",
            "SomethingElse"
        )
        log.debug("Received response: {}", putRecordResponse)
    }
}

Now the question is how do i configure the firehose client either using arn or using access_key and secret_key ? I am getting the following error software.amazon.awssdk.core.exception.SdkClientException: Unable to execute HTTP request: No X509TrustManager implementation available  while running service I think its related to not setting the client properly, i.e. it is missing credentials, but i dont know how to use the credentials. If anyone has any idea or has any experience, then kindly help. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you in advance
P.S. all the code is in Kotlin
